# unity web request got error for local files on mobile

Tags: unity-game-engine, unitywebrequest

I load images from my local destination to unity the code is:

```
    Texture2D imgTexture;
    using (UnityWebRequest req = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(filePath))
    {
        yield return req.SendWebRequest();
        if (req.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.Log(req.error);
        }
        else
        {
            imgTexture = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(req);
        }
    }
```

it works on pc but when I run on android emulator I get an error

> Cannot connect to destination host

the local file directory comes from simple file browsing plugin so I am thinking directory cannot be wrong.
is it a permission problem how can I fix this?

Comment: Could you add the value of `filePath` or how you get it?

Comment: As Hugo mentioned we also need your `filePath` variable, my guess would be that you're not pointing it to `jar:file//` on Android, which is required if you want to access folders like the streaming assets.

Comment: I am using "simple file browser" plugin.I select the picture and returned file path from emulator is "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/picture.jpg"

Comment: try and checkout https://forum.unity.com/threads/unitywebrequest-for-local-files-on-android-failure.441655/ .. you need something like `jar:file// + filePath` or `file// + filePath`

Comment: thx I will try this

Comment: sorry to write back this late file:// works thanks.